# eww browser is hanging at contacting duckduckgo

Tags: eww

I’m trying out eww. I followed the instructions on [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eww.html) page, and there seems to be no mention of what might be going on. I’m not getting an error message. I’ve run `eww RET <somekeyword>`
With a few different keywords, and I always see at the top: `[untitled]: https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=thing`, and at the bottom, `contacting host: duckduckgo.com:443`. I’ve waited for over two minutes, and my internet connection is fine.

What might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The default search engine used by eww can be configured by changing **[eww-search-prefix](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/net/eww.el#L54-L58)**.  You can customize it like this:

```lisp
(setq eww-search-prefix "https://lite.duckduckgo.com/lite/?q=")
```

Answer (score 0):

The default search engine in emacs-w3m has now been update to duckduck/lite because of this problem. Either update your emacs-w3m package or try searching by using the explicitly URL https://duckduckgo.com/lite.

Comment: I am uncertain how to do either. Does (1) emacs have a package manager from which I update things, (2) it is unclear how to change the url

Comment: I have entered https://duckduckgo.com/lite, it is not resolving.

Comment: i also have this issue. https://duckduckgo.com/lite also doesn't resolve. but when i load a searx instance, it works.